# The command 'cmd /S /C choco install --no-progress -y curl' returned a non-zero code: 3221225785

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, chocolatey

I was installing using chocolatey `curl` in a windows docker image using the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
ENV chocolateyUseWindowsCompression="true"           
RUN powershell.exe -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
RUN choco install --no-progress -y curl
```

This was working well, but since a couple of days, this was now failing with the error :

```
Step 5/8 : RUN choco install --no-progress -y curl    
 ---> Running in 7d1c2e12d931    
Chocolatey v0.10.15    
Installing the following packages:    
curl    
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.     
curl v7.69.0 [Approved]     
curl package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.    
Extracting 64-bit C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\curl\tools\curl-7.69.0-win64-mingw.zip to C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\curl\tools...    
ERROR: 7-Zip signalled an unknown error (code -1073741511) This is most likely an issue with the 'curl' package and not with Chocolatey itself. Please follow up with the package maintainer(s) directly.    
The install of curl was NOT successful.    
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\curl\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.    
 See log for details.    
Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.    
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).    
Failures    
 - curl (exited -1073741511) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\curl\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.    
 See log for details.    
The command 'cmd /S /C choco install --no-progress -y curl' returned a non-zero code: 3221225785     
C:\Windows\TEMP\cirrus-ci-build>if -1073741511 NEQ 0 exit /b -1073741511     
Exit status: 3221225785
```

I tried to change the base image using mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809, but it fails the same.

What could be the reason of this failure ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error code when running a silent msi installer as part of creating a docker image. Have you tried with mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909 as the base image?

Comment: I am using cirrusci to build images, it doesnot support release `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909`, but it is working wirth `cirrusci/windowsservercore:2019`. I did not understand what change break choco installation

Answer (score 1):

I am running into the same problem on a Jenkins node, but I am unable to reproduce the problem localy.

That's why I think it's a problem with the host-system.

Locally I am running on Windows10 (1909 Build 18363.959) thats fine with everything.
On a Jenkins-Node is a "Windows Server 2019 (amd64)" System.

- Currently I am contacting the Administrator to get further informations

**UPDATE**
using older version "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-20190709-windowsservercore-ltsc2019" works!