# Troubles installing anything in Docker Container on Windows Server 2016/2019 VM

Tags: python, docker, virtual-machine, windows-server-2016, chocolatey

I'm trying to install my toolchain in a docker container on a windows 2016 server VM but everything is failing to install and gives a random error code. I am using Chocolatey to install these tools but I have attempted to download the exe directly and run it however nothing happens and has an exit code of 0.
Python Output from Chocolatey when attempting to run
`choco install python -y`:

[image]

My build environment is Windows 19041 running a Windows `Hyper-V` Server 2016 VM
(`Windows 10[host] -> Server 2016[VM] -> Docker`). I've tried to search the issue and reviewed the logs but nothing I can find is working.

To make this even more confusing, it works on Windows Server 2022 Preview but not for 2019 or 2016.

Error message:

```
ERROR: Running ["C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\python-3.9.6-amd64.exe" /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 TargetDir="C:\Python39" ] was not successful. Exit code was '-1073741511'. See log for possible error messages.
The install of python3 was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

Comment: This is on-topic for stack overflow as it addresses an issue with installing development tools using a code-based deployment tool often used during development and testing. See the third bullet of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Can you update your question with raw text of the terminal output instead of a screenshot? This makes it more easily searchable and readable.

Comment: So that link you provided suggests on-topic is:
"..
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"
How does this question not fit? If it doesn't hit, it's more useful and friendly to suggest where I should ask this question (though I believe this does fit because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302932/chocolatey-install-package-failing and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582705/the-command-cmd-s-c-choco-install-no-progress-y-curl-returned-a-non-zero and more have similar issues but were not closed).

Comment: Also I did post the error code (see error message). I just need to figure out a solution to this. Having it closed for a generic reason and no direction isn't useful

Comment: My comment was meant to point out that this is on topic and *should not be closed*. That said it also would be on topic for ServerFault or SuperUser, but it's not inappropriate for Stack Overflow. That is what a closed question implies; that it does not fit here. I submitted a reopen request but it's not a decision one can make unilaterally. You can always ask on meta.stackoverflow.com as to why this was closed when it should be on topic, usually that will get some others' attention.

Comment: SO has moderators but much of the moderation work is done by the community. Sometimes folks get overzealous with their close votes.

Comment: Oh Bender, I apologize. I read it as off-topic - thank you for helping me with that. One would say I got overzealous hahaha but seriously, I'm sorry for the misunderstanding there.